# Posting Quickbooks Online invoice without using CustomerRef

Tags: xml, quickbooks, invoice

How do I create an invoice in QBO without using the CustomerRef field? Every example just shows:

```
<CustomerRef name="ACME Inc">2</CustomerRef>
```

Do I ALWAYS have to look up the Id? Can't I just post to "ACME Inc" without finding the ref # (2)? The older QBXML did this no problem.

Similarly for items, they all have it like this:

```
<ItemRef name="Hours">2</ItemRef>
```

How do I just specify "Hours" and have QB look it up for me?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I create an invoice in QBO without using the CustomerRef field?

You can't.

> Do I ALWAYS have to look up the Id?

Yes. Or cache it in your application.

> Can't I just post to "ACME Inc" without finding the ref # (2)?

No.

> The older QBXML did this no problem.

The QBO v3 APIs bear little-to-no resemblence to the old qbXML. It's apples to oranges.

> How do I just specify "Hours" and have QB look it up for me?

You can't.

You must specify the `Id` value. This is the only thing the QBO v3 APIs support.